# Rails 'button_tag' to define variable

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= 
 button_tag class: "btn btn-primary",
 data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#exampleModal", name: member.name } do
    modal_member = Member.find(member.id)
    content_tag(:b, 'Open Modal')
 end           
 %>
```

I'm going to make variable name 'modal_member' 
with button_tag

because bootstrap modal but it doesn't work

I think that define code doesn't do well

My goal is define or pass the variable to button or link tag

Comment: Don't put the (deprecated) `b` tag into that `button` tag.

Comment: You better not do this way because you are making a request to DB from view, not a best practice. What I mean is you already have `member` in your variables, Don't do extra `Member.find`. Secondly, just insert the modal structure in your html and fill it with `member` data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise to insert the modal structure right into your erb file and then just fill it with data you want. Unless you are triggering it via js, that would be a different story.

```html
<%= 
 button_tag class: "btn btn-primary",
 data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#exampleModal", name: member.name } do
    content_tag(:b, 'Open Modal')
 end           
 %>
 <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> <%= member.name %> or whatever data you want</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for your answer! but I repeated button
use .each method

then that modal member.name comes to only one

Comment: Oh I solve the problem becuz of your answer!! THX so much